# About float to int

Tags: c++

```
float x = 2.5;
int i = (int)x;
```

We all know the result is 2, but I want to know why we get this result, what is the theory and how the system work? Can it be explained using binary form (IEEE)?

Comment: We get this result because it is required by the language specification. The language specification could have required this to produce `25` in `i`. In that case it would have happily produced `25`. I.e. there's no "theory" behind it and the result has no relation to any "binary form". There's only a requirement, which is implemented by any means necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in the C++ Standard (Draft Standard N3337)

> **4.9 Floating-integral conversions**
>
> 1 A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ *Note*: If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. — *end note* ]

Answer (score 2):

C++11 §4.9/1:

> **”** The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.

That’s it, the theory of it: *because the standard says so*.

It's a reasonable language design choice but by no means the only possible reasonable choice.